# How to track the user that is sending messages to kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

We're currently facing some issue to track the client that's sending lots of messages (unnecessary) to a kafka topic.
In other words, how can I track(producer), who's sending messages to a particular kakfa topic?

I've tried verifying all the logs (server.log) but wa able to see the logs related to topic names (partitions etc.,.) but nothing related to client.

Is there a way to track?

Comment: Have you tried logging with org.apache.kafka.clients set to DEBUG?  I'm thinking that might be a good start.

Comment: did you find the answer? I faced a similar problem and found only one solution - send information about the producer in Kafka headers

Comment: not if the client using plaintext to communicate with kafka. If they use SASL_SSL;at-least we can track using the Functional ID.Otherwise it's really hard